# About global norms and product of local norms

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $L/K$ be an extension of number fields, and let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime in $\mathcal{O}_K$, and assume $\mathfrak{P}_i$ are all the prime in $\mathcal{O}_L$ lying over $\mathfrak{p}$. Also consider the completions $K_{\mathfrak{p}}$ and $L_{\mathfrak{P}_i}$. Let $\mathfrak{P}:=\mathfrak{P}_1$, and let $D_{\mathfrak{P}}$ be the decomposition group, and $\tau_iD_{\mathfrak{P}}$ are the different cosets of $D_{\mathfrak{P}}$ in $Gal(L/K)$ such that $\tau_i(\mathfrak{P})=\mathfrak{P}_i$. And $N_{L_{\mathfrak{P}_i}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}}$ is the norm from $L_{\mathfrak{P}_i}$ to $K_{\mathfrak{p}}$.

I want to prove $N_{L/K}(\alpha)=N_{L_{\mathfrak{P}}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}}(\prod\tau_i(\alpha))$.

My attempts: I know that we have $N_{L/K}(\alpha)=\prod N_{L_{\mathfrak{P}_i}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}}(\alpha)$, I guessed we should have $N_{L_{\mathfrak{P}_i}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}}(\alpha)=N_{L_{\mathfrak{P}}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}}(\tau_i^{-1}\alpha)$ (or something like this). If we have that relation. then everything is stratighforward:
$$N_{L/K}(\alpha)
=\prod N_{L_{\mathfrak{P}_i}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}}(\alpha)
=\prod N_{L_{\mathfrak{P}}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}}(\tau_i^{-1}\alpha)
=\prod N_{L_{\mathfrak{P}}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}}(\tau_i\alpha)
=N_{L_{\mathfrak{P}}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}}(\prod\tau_i(\alpha)),$$
but to me the this (I mean "$N_{L_{\mathfrak{P}_i}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}}(\alpha)=N_{L_{\mathfrak{P}}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}}(\tau_i^{-1}\alpha)$") is very suspicious and I can't prove it, and I have some doubts about it.

I think it should be a simple Galois theoretic argument, but I am very confused about too many details, and too many norms etc.

> I mean can we show that $N_{L_{\mathfrak{P}_i}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}}(\alpha)=N_{L_{\mathfrak{P}}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}}(\tau_i^{-1}\alpha)$?

> Can we eliminate the Galois condition?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean $L/K$ is Galois and $D_{\mathfrak{P}}\tau_i$ instead of $\tau_i D_{\mathfrak{P}}$?

This way $$N_{L/K}(\alpha) = \prod_{\sigma\in Gal(L/K)} \sigma(\alpha)=\prod_i \prod_{\sigma \in D_{\mathfrak{P}}\tau_i} \sigma(\alpha)$$ $$ = \prod_i \prod_{\rho\in D_{\mathfrak{P}}} \rho(\tau_i(\alpha)) = 
\prod_{\rho\in D_{\mathfrak{P}}} \rho( \prod_i \tau_i(\alpha)) 
=
N_{L_{\mathfrak{P}}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}}(\prod_i \tau_i(\alpha))$$
The result $N_{L/K}(\alpha) = N_{L_{\mathfrak{P}}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}}(\prod_i \tau_i(\alpha))$ makes sense in $K_{\mathfrak{p}}$, or in $L$ if the
$L_{\mathfrak{P}}\to K_{\mathfrak{p}}$ function
$N_{L_{\mathfrak{P}}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}}$ is restricted to a function $L\to L$.

If you really meant $Gal(L/K)=\bigcup_i\tau_i D_{\mathfrak{P}}$ then $Gal(L/K)=\bigcup_i  D_{\mathfrak{P}}\tau_i^{-1}$ so that $N_{L/K}(\alpha) =N_{L_{\mathfrak{P}}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}}(\prod_i \tau_i^{-1}(\alpha))$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am reading your answer. If we assume we are in a Galois extension, then I have three questions: (A) The Galois group of $L_{\mathfrak{P}}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is precisely $D_{\mathfrak{P}}$, am I right? (B) $N_{L_{\mathfrak{P}}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}}(\beta)=\prod_{\rho \in D_{\mathfrak{P}}}\rho(\beta)$? Sorry for these questions. (C) My third question is: If we have the Galois assumption, then what is the difference between the left cosets and right cosets? Left cosets $\tau_i D_{\mathfrak{P}}$ are coincide with $D_{\mathfrak{P}}\tau_i$.

Comment: Yes for A and B. $D_\mathfrak{P}$ doesn't have to be a normal subgroup.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that, thanks for your patience. I also edited my question, I think if we consider the right cosets then we can provide something about $N_{L_{\mathfrak{P}_i}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}}(\alpha)=N_{L_{\mathfrak{P}}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}}(\tau_i^{-1}\alpha)$. Is it possible to reform my solution, based on this relation?